Problemas con envío JSON
Hola tengo un codigo en php que al final para poder enviarlo por json utilizo json_encode(), pero por algun motivo al archivo que llega le sale este error en la consola: SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<', "<!DOCTYPE "... is not valid JSON. Tengo entendido que ese error es cuando le llega información como html y no como json, he revisado el código ya por varios días y no encuentro el error. Alguien por favor me puede ayudar.
este es el código:
<?php


header('Content-Type: application/json');


if (!defined('JSON_INVALID_UTF8_SUBSTITUTE')) {
    define('JSON_INVALID_UTF8_SUBSTITUTE', 0); // Ajusta el valor según tus necesidades
}


ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

require 'controlador/config.php';

// Filtro de búsqueda por término
$campo = isset($_POST['campo']) ? $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['campo']) : null;
$whereConditions = [];
$whereConditions2 = [];
if (!empty($campo)) {
    foreach ($columns as $column) {
        $whereConditions2[] = "$column LIKE '%$campo%'";
    }
    $whereConditions[] = "(" . implode(" OR ", $whereConditions2) . ")";
}

// Filtro de tipo de transacción
$tipo = isset($_POST['tipo']) ? $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['tipo']) : null;
if (!empty($tipo)) {
    switch ($tipo) {
        case 'venta':
            $whereConditions[] = "tra = 'venta'";
            break;
        case 'arriendo':
            $whereConditions[] = "tra = 'arriendo'";
            break;
        case 'vcasa':
            $whereConditions[] = "tra = 'venta' AND tpro = 'casa'";
            break;
        case 'vdepartamento':
            $whereConditions[] = "tra = 'venta' AND tpro = 'departamento'";
            break;
        case 'acasa':
            $whereConditions[] = "tra = 'arriendo' AND tpro = 'casa'";
            break;
        case 'adepartamento':
            $whereConditions[] = "tra = 'arriendo' AND tpro = 'departamento'";
            break;
        default:
            // Tipo no reconocido
            break;
    }
}

if (!empty($whereConditions)) {
    $where = "WHERE " . implode(" AND ", $whereConditions);
} else {
    $where = ""; // No hay condiciones de filtrado
}


// Limites
$limit = isset($_POST['registros']) ? $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['registros']) : 10;
$pagina = isset($_POST['pagina']) ? $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['pagina']) : 0;

if (!$pagina) {
    $inicio = 0;
    $pagina = 1;
} else {
    $inicio = ($pagina - 1) * $limit;
}

$sLimit = "LIMIT $inicio , $limit";

// Ordenamiento

$sOrder = "";
if (isset($_POST['orderCol'])) {
    $orderCol = $_POST['orderCol'];
    $oderType = isset($_POST['orderType']) ? $_POST['orderType'] : 'asc';

    $sOrder = "ORDER BY " . $columns[intval($orderCol)] . ' ' . $oderType;
}

// Consulta
$sql = "(SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS *
         FROM casas
        )
        UNION ALL
        (SELECT *
         FROM departamentos
        )
         $sOrder $sLimit  $where";
$resultado = $conn->query($sql);
$num_rows = $resultado->num_rows;



// Consulta para total de registro filtrados
$sqlFiltro = "SELECT FOUND_ROWS()";
$resFiltro = $conn->query($sqlFiltro);
$row_filtro = $resFiltro->fetch_array();
$totalFiltro = $row_filtro[0];

// Consulta para total de registro
$sqlTotal = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS totalRegistros FROM (
    SELECT * FROM casas
    UNION ALL
    SELECT * FROM departamentos
) AS registrosCombinados";
$resTotal = $conn->query($sqlTotal);
$row_total = $resTotal->fetch_array();
$totalRegistros = $row_total[0];


// Mostrado resultados
$output = [];
$output['totalRegistros'] = $totalRegistros;
$output['totalFiltro'] = $totalFiltro;
$output['data'] = '';
$output['paginacion'] = '';

// Define el esqueleto del HTML con marcadores de posición para los datos
$htmlSkeleton = "
<tbody>
<div class='propiedades'>
<table class='tabla1'>
    <tr>  
        <td class='celda1'>{{contador}}</td>
        <td class='celda2'><img width='200' height='200' src='data:image/jpg;base64,{{base64Image}}' alt='foto casa' /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<table class='tabla2'> 
    <tr>
        <td class='sort asc'>Comuna: {{comuna}}</td>
        <td class='sort asc' >Dormitorios: {{dormitorios}}</td>
        <td class='sort asc' >Baños: {{banos}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<table class='tabla3'> 
    <tr>
        <td class='sort asc' >Precio: {{valor}}</td>
        <td class='sort asc' >Tipo: {{tra}}</td>
        <td class='sort asc' >Tipo: {{tpro}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<form method='POST' name='busqueda' id='busqueda' action='ver.php?id={{id}}'>
<input style='opacity: 0;' type='text' name='busqueda' id='busqueda' placeholder='Buscar' class='serie' value='{{comuna}}'>
<input class='enviar' type='submit' name='enviar' id='busqueda' value='Ver'>
</form>
</div>
</tbody>";

if ($num_rows > 0) {
    $contador=0;
    while ($row = $resultado->fetch_assoc()) {
        $contador++;
        foreach ($row as $key => $value) {
        
        }$encoding = mb_detect_encoding($value, mb_detect_order(), true);
        if ($encoding) {
            $row[$key] = mb_convert_encoding($value, 'UTF-8', $encoding);
        } else {
            // La codificación no se pudo detectar, manejar el caso aquí
        }

        $imageData = $row['imagen'];

        $base64Image = base64_encode($imageData);
       
        $filaHtml = str_replace(
            ['{{contador}}', '{{base64Image}}', '{{id}}','{{comuna}}', '{{dormitorios}}', '{{banos}}', '{{valor}}', '{{tra}}', '{{tpro}}'],
            [$contador, base64_encode($row['imagen']),$row['id'], $row['comuna'], $row['dormitorios'], $row['banos'], $row['valor'], $row['tra'], $row['tpro']],
            $htmlSkeleton
        );

        // Agrega esta fila al output final
        $output['data'] .= $filaHtml;
    }
} else {
    $output['data'] = "<div id='myModal' class='modal' style='display: block;'>
    <div class='modal-content'>
        <p>¡NO EXISTEN RESULTADOS PARA PARAMETROS UTILIZADOS! Por favor cambielos.</p>
    </div>
</div>";
                    
}

// Paginación
if ($totalRegistros > 0) {
    $totalPaginas = ceil($totalFiltro / $limit);

    $output['paginacion'] .= '<nav>';
    $output['paginacion'] .= '<ul class="pagination">';

    $numeroInicio = max(1, $pagina - 4);
    $numeroFin = min($totalPaginas, $numeroInicio + 9);

    for ($i = $numeroInicio; $i <= $numeroFin; $i++) {
        $output['paginacion'] .= '<li class="page-item' . ($pagina == $i ? ' active' : '') . '">';
        $output['paginacion'] .= '<a class="page-link" href="#" onclick="nextPage(' . $i . ')">' . $i . '</a>';
        $output['paginacion'] .= '</li>';
    }

    $output['paginacion'] .= '</ul>';
    $output['paginacion'] .= '</nav>';
}

echo json_encode($output, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE | JSON_INVALID_UTF8_SUBSTITUTE);

Si pueden ver en que parte del código se esta produciendo el error. Por Favor.
llega a este archivo de nombre index.php:
<?php
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['usuario'])) {
    // Redirige a la página de inicio de sesión o muestra un mensaje de error.
    header("Location:login/login.php");
    exit;
}



 $user_id=$_SESSION['id'] ; // Donde $user_id es el ID del usuario autenticado.


 echo '<p style="color: black; position:absolute; right: 50px;">Bienvenid@: ' . $_SESSION['usuario'] . '</p>';

?>





<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="description" content="Buscar datos en tiempo real con PHP, MySQL y AJAX">
    <meta name="author" content="Rafael Ventura">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="estilos.css">
    <title>Fullproperties</title>


    <style>
            input[class="enviar"] {
                position: absolute;
                width: 200px;
                height: 200px;
                left: 15px;
                background-color: #f1f1f1;
                color: black;
                font-size: 16px;
                top:0px;z
                border: none;
                cursor: pointer;
                border-radius: 5px;
                text-align: center;
                border: 5px solid #dea909;
                opacity: 0;

            }

            input[type="submit"]:hover {
                color: white;
                color:brightness(5.4);
            }

.modal {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 20%;
    height: 50%;
    overflow: auto;
    z-index: 20;
}

.modal-content {
    background-color: #fefefe;
    margin: 15% auto;
    padding: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #888;
    width: 80%;
}

        </style>


</head>
<div>
<h1 class="logotipo">Full  Properties</h1>

<img class="logo" src="img/logo.jpg">
<header>
    <div class="contenedor">
        <nav>
            <a href="http://www.fullproperties.cl/vendetucasa.php" class="activo">Vende tu casa</a>
            /
            <a href="login/registro.php">Registro</a>
            /
            <a href="controlador/cerrar_sesion.php">Cerrar sesión</a>
            /   
            <a href="contacto.php">Contacto</a>  
            /
            <a href="casas/formulario_casas.php">Intranet</a>

        </nav>
    </div>
</header>

<div class ="mega">
    <main>
        <div class="pelicula-principal">
            <div class="contenedor1">
                <h3 class="titulo">Juntos podemos vender más</h3>
            </div>
        </div>
    </main>

<body>
  

        <div class="tnueva1">

                <div class="tnueva2">
                    <label for="tnueva3" class="col-form-label">Mostrar: </label>
                </div>

                <div class="tnueva4">
                    <select name="num_registros" id="num_registros" class="form-select">
                        <option value="10">10</option>
                        <option value="20">20</option>
                        <option value="45">45</option>
                        <option value="100">100</option>
                    </select>
                </div>

              

                <div class="col-md-4 col-xl-5"></div>

                <div class="tnueva7">
                    <label for="campo" class="col-form-label">Buscar: </label>
                </div>
                <div class="tnueva8">
                    <input type="text" name="campo" id="campo" class="form-control" style="text-indent: 10px;" >
                </div>
            
                <div class="tnueva13">
    <label for="tipo" class="col-form-label">Tipo de transacción:</label>
</div>
<div class="tnueva14">
    <select id="tipo" name="tipo">
        <option value=""></option>
        <optgroup label="Venta">
            <option value="venta">Venta</option>
            <option value="vcasa">Venta - Casa</option>
            <option value="vdepartamento">Venta - Departamento</option>
        </optgroup>
        <optgroup label="Arriendo">
            <option value="arriendo">Arriendo</option>
            <option value="acasa">Arriendo - Casa</option>
            <option value="adepartamento">Arriendo - Departamento</option>
        </optgroup>
    </select>
</div>
            
                <table class="tnueva9">
                        <thead>
                            <th class="sort asc">Comuna</th>
                            <th class="sort asc">Dormitorios</th>
                            <th class="sort asc">Baños</th>
                            <th class="sort asc">Valor</th>
                            <th></th>
                            <th></th>
                        </thead>
                    

                        <!-- El id del cuerpo de la tabla. -->
                    <div class="tnueva" id="content">  
                    </div>
                </table>
           
                 
            <div class="tnueva10">

                <div class="tnueva11">
                    <label id="lbl-total"></label>
                </div>

                <div class="tnueva12" id="nav-paginacion"></div>

                <input type="hidden" id="pagina" value="1">
                <input type="hidden" id="orderCol" value="0">
                <input type="hidden" id="orderType" value="asc">

            </div>
        </div>
</div>

    <script>


        // Llamando a la función getData() al cargar la página
        document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", getData);

        // Función para obtener datos con AJAX
        function getData() {


            let inputTipo = document.getElementById("tipo").value
            let input = document.getElementById("campo").value
            let num_registros = document.getElementById("num_registros").value
            let content = document.getElementById("content")
            let pagina = document.getElementById("pagina").value || 10;
            let orderCol = document.getElementById("orderCol").value
            let orderType = document.getElementById("orderType").value

            let formaData = new FormData()
            formaData.append('tipo', inputTipo)
            formaData.append('campo', input)
            formaData.append('registros', num_registros)
            formaData.append('pagina', pagina)
            formaData.append('orderCol', orderCol)
            formaData.append('orderType', orderType)
            
            fetch("./load.php", {
                    method: "POST",
                    body: formaData
                })
                .then(response => response.json())
                .then(data => {
                    content.innerHTML = data.data
                    document.getElementById("lbl-total").innerHTML = `Mostrando ${data.totalFiltro} de ${data.totalRegistros} registros`;
                    document.getElementById("nav-paginacion").innerHTML = data.paginacion

                    // Si la página actual no tiene resultados, ajustar la paginación para mostrar la primera página
                    if (data.data.includes('NO EXISTEN RESULTADOS PARA PARAMETROS UTILIZADOS') && parseInt(pagina) !== 1) {
                        nextPage(1); // Ir a la primera página
                    }
                })
                .catch(err => console.log(err))
                console.log("orderCol:", document.getElementById('orderCol').value);
            console.log("orderType:", document.getElementById("orderType").value);
        }

        // Función para cambiar de página
        function nextPage(pagina) {
            document.getElementById('pagina').value = pagina
            getData()
        }

        // Función para ordenar columnas
        function ordenar(e) {
            let elemento = e.target;
            let orderType = elemento.classList.contains("asc") ? "desc" : "asc";

            document.getElementById('orderCol').value = elemento.cellIndex;
            document.getElementById("orderType").value = orderType;
            elemento.classList.toggle("asc");
            elemento.classList.toggle("desc");

        

            getData()
        }

        // Event listeners para los eventos de cambio en el campo de entrada y el select
        document.getElementById("tipo").addEventListener("click", getData);
        document.getElementById("campo").addEventListener("keyup", getData);
        document.getElementById("num_registros").addEventListener("change",getData);

        // Event listener para ordenar las columnas
        let columns = document.querySelectorAll(".sort");
        columns.forEach(column => {
            column.addEventListener("click", ordenar);
        });

    </script>



    <!-- Bootstrap core JS -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-YvpcrYf0tY3lHB60NNkmXc5s9fDVZLESaAA55NDzOxhy9GkcIdslK1eN7N6jIeHz" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>


¿Por qué estás tratando de enviar como JSON un HTML (lo que estás guardando en $output)?

Depura tu código con un var_dump($output); y verifica que ese contenido es válido para pasarlo a json_encode. Nosotros no tenemos todo el contexto para poder decirte qué es lo que está mal. Otra cosa que puedes hacer es revisar el registro de errores en tu entorno PHP. También para aclarar, conviene que nos digas si parte de tu JSON sería contenido HTML. De ser así, debes cuidar cosas como las comillas dobles en el contenido. Si no las escapas correctamente, van a romper tu JSON.

En el archivo al que le llega, antes de intentar decodificar o interpretar el JSON, saca el contenido recibido a la consola. Apuesto una cerveza a que verás un HTML conteniendo algún error. ¿Estás validando el status? Diría que no va a ser un status 200, sino que estás recibiendo otro, un 4XX o un 5XX entre los más probables.  Sin ver el código de ese "otro archivo", es difícil decir algo más aterrizado.

@padaleiana, estoy creando una pagina de publicación de propiedades y creo una estructura HTML dinámica, para poder filtrarla, según lo que necesite el usuario que las va a buscar.

@jachguate Este es el código del archivo, solo la parte de  donde llega JSON:
        fetch("./load.php", {
                method: "POST",
                body: formaData
            })
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => {
                content.innerHTML = data.data
                document.getElementById("lbl-total").innerHTML = `Mostrando ${data.totalFiltro} de ${data.totalRegistros} registros`;
                document.getElementById("nav-paginacion").innerHTML = data.paginacion


Por favor, no publiques código en comentarios, dale clic en [edit] la pregunta y publicalo en ella. Saludos.

@jachguate, ok perdon no sabia que esa era la forma

@Rafael, te invito entonces a hacer de nuevo el [tour]. Allí se explica el funcionamiento del sitio. Un saludo.
